# Latex command line compiler can't find image files, but Gummi can

Tags: graphics, compilation-error, command-line

I am trying to compile a latex document in Linux; however, the images are not being found from the command line, despite them being found in Gummi. I am running `latex [document_name]` from the Linux command line and I am using the following tex code for the figures:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{waveplot_norm_ann}
\end{figure}
```

The image is a png file in the same directory as the latex source file. The error I get when trying to compile is as follows:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `waveplot_norm_ann' not found.
```

Does anyone know why Gummi can find it, but the command line compiler can't?

Comment: latex can't use png files, you need `pdflatex`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah, I hadn't realized that. That's a huge help, thanks!

Comment: See the compilation preferences of Gummi, you can use pdftex (with preloaded format pdflatex) xetex (xelatex) or luatex (lualatex) but not "latex" (that is aldo pdftex but with other preloaded format). Latex is to produce DVI files, not PF files, an use only  EPS images. That was the prehistoric way to do  the document. Today is used mostly by nostalgic reasons.

Comment: @Fran ok, thanks, this is good info. I was actually trying to locally compile an academic paper I'm working on, and the template from the journal said to run `latex ...`. I'm not even sure what DVI files are.

Comment: DVI is a DeVice Independent format,  like PDF, but older. Today there are still DVI viewers like advi, and support to DVI files in PDF viewers (evince, atril in Linux)  or almost  (okular),  and tools to convert DVI files to PDF, PNG, PS; SVG ... but today you can live safely without worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt console and go to the directory that your .tex file resides. Issue the following command:

```
$ pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode your_latex_file.tex
```

If you can see the auxiliary files and your_latex_file.pdf then it means the Texmaker setting is wrong. Probably it executes `latex` instead of `pdflatex` command.

Right side of "Run" button on toolbar you can set the compiler to PDFLaTeX and it should work.